# How use correct href in function php?

Tags: php, wordpress

How use correct next href in function php?

```
function log(){
    if (is_user_logged_in()){
        echo '<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( home_url() ); ?>">'.log.'</a>';
    }
}
```

In this time result is 403 error.

Comment: Your first echo is already in the PHP code, so you don't switch to PHP using <?php when you're already in PHP.... concatenate the strings that you're echoing

Comment: The `.log.` is probably wrong as well - is this meant to be a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant echo an echo, it should be:

```
function log(){
    if (is_user_logged_in()){
        echo '<a href="' . wp_logout_url( home_url() ) . '"> log </a>';
    }
}
```

Also i'm not sure what `log` is you have it outside the string so it will be evaluated and throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Do not include `<?php ?>` in PHP scripts, and do not try to echo it through PHP.

Simply do this:

```
function log(){
    if (is_user_logged_in()){
        $wplogout = wp_logout_url( home_url() );
        echo '<a href="{$wplogout}">'.log.'</a>';
    }
}
```